# After a slide, keep a position

Tags: jquery, css

I have two contents who exchanging their positions (green and red for the example).

At the beginning the green content is shifted from 150px from the left. But after a full turn this content is recovering from left to 0px. How to make this content returns to 150px from the left after a full turn ?

Click on the "image button" at the top right hand corner to see : http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/CnSEa/7/

```
$('#content-clients').css('left', '150%');

$('#btn-clients').click(function () {

    $("#main ul:first").animate({
        left: '-150%'
    }, 500, function () {
        $(this).css('left', '150%');
        $(this).appendTo('#main');
    });

    $('#main ul:first').next().animate({
        left: '0'
    }, 500);
});
```

I FOUND ! http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/CnSEa/19/

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/CnSEa/10/ You have left set to zero in your JS.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but unfortunately the red content is set to 150px too and rightly I don't want. That's why is a little bit complicated. How to add a condition like this : If the next content is green (#content-scene) add left: 150px but if it's the red (#content-clients) left:0 ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overthinking this. Just use `toggleClass()` to add and remove a new class with a different `left` position. Then when you remove the class it will use the original `left` position you have set. Take a look [at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CnSEa/13/) you can see that the green box returns to its original `left:150px` once you remove the class you added and the red box uses its `left:0`.

Comment: This is a great logic ! The only problem is the animation. This it's not longer a slide it's a sort of exchange from the right

Comment: All you would have to do is tweak the fiddle a bit that I linked. Add a 2nd class that slides the ul in the other direction then switch it over to the right to give the illusion its looping around. I would tweak it but I'm bust at the moment, hopefully the logic points you in the right direction though

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have found. I add two conditions : http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/CnSEa/19/

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for trouble mixing px and % in your animations. Best to be consistent. For example, replace -150% with `0 - $(this).width()`, replace 150% with `$('#main').width() + $('#main').offset().left`.

Comment: Thank you. I use % to hide the contents. After this contents are replaced at left:0 with next().animate() function. I tried to put 150px but the two contents are replaced at 150px from the left and I would like that only the green content be replace at 150px. I don't know if I'm clear lol